# How can I separate a list of things inside one cell into several cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this cell that has a list of things, for example:

```
[dogs, cats, mice, cows, horses]
```

And I want to separate them in different cells:

```
[dogs]
[cats]
[mice]
[cows]
[horses]
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, It can be done with formulas, text to columns, and vba.  What have you tried?

Comment: Quickly, to do exactly what you said - run Text to Columns (under Data tab), use comma as a delimiter, then copy the row, right click Paste Special --> Transpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in `VBA`:

```
Sub splitString ()
    Dim ran, splitS() As String
    ran = Range("A1")
    splitS() = Split(ran, ",")
    For j = LBound(splitS) To UBound(splitS)
    Range("B" & (j + 1)) = splitS(j)
    Next j
End Sub
```

If you also want the *square brackets*, use this code below:

```
Sub splitStringWithSquareBrackets()
    Dim ran, splitS() As String
    ran = Range("A1")
    ran = Right(ran, Len(ran) - 1)
    ran = Left(ran, Len(ran) - 1)
    splitS() = Split(ran, ",")
    For j = LBound(splitS) To UBound(splitS)
    Range("B" & (j + 1)) = "[" & splitS(j) & "]"
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious - any particular reason you didn't declare `ran` as a `Range`?  I would have thought you'd get an error since you just do `ran = Range("A1")` instead of `Set ran = Range("A1")`. ...what's the `Variant` actually storing, the cell address of `A1`?

Comment: I can't split a range, because a range is a path to a cell and Split() only accepts strings.

Comment: @BruceWayne he is getting the `.Value` which is the default.

Comment: Ahh, duh, I should've realized that.  Also, good to know `Split` runs on a string only, as I was going to suggest just remove `ran = ` line and just use the `Range("A1")` in `Split()`.  Thanks for your comment, and @ScottCraner!

Answer (score 0):

This would do it - You have to select the cell with the cell before running it and it assumes that there is closed brackets ("[" and "]") on either end.

I'll have my best answer now..

```
Sub ImAmazing()
Dim sString As String, i As Long

If Trim(ActiveCell.Value) = "" Then Exit Sub

ActiveCell.Value = Mid(ActiveCell.Value, 2, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 2)

Do Until InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ",") = 0
    i = i + 1
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + i, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "[" & Left(ActiveCell.Value, InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ",") - 1) & "]"
    ActiveCell.Value = Right(ActiveCell.Value, (Len(ActiveCell.Value) - InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ",") - 1))
Loop

ActiveCell.Value = "[" & ActiveCell.Value & "]"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use VBA's Split() function?

Comment: @matt_black no particularly good reason - this is just usually the way I do it (though I can see `Split()` is often the better option

Answer (score 0):

With data in cell **A1**:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, i As Long

    s = Range("A1").Value
    s = Mid(s, 2, Len(s) - 2)
    ary = Split(s, ", ")
    i = 2

    For Each a In ary
        Cells(i, "A").Value = "[" & a & "]"
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image]